# Query large list with indexed column doesnt work

Tags: 2013, csom, list-view-threshold, large-lists

I am querying a large list and it works well if I don't put any condition in where clause.

I am trying to get items greater than some `ID`(actual requirement is to get items `Created > Today()`), as soon as I introduce this condition the query fails with below error :

> Additional information: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

```
ListItemCollectionPosition itemPosition = null;
                while(true)
                {
                    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = itemPosition;
                    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>"+
                                    "<Query>" +
                                       "<Where>" +
                                          "<Gt>" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
                                            "<Value Type='Counter'>80000</Value>" +
                                         "</Gt>" +
                                       "</Where>" +
                                       "</Query>" +     
                                        "<ViewFields>"+
                                         "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                                         "<FieldRef Name='Created'/>" +
                                         "<FieldRef Name='SRNumber'/>" +
                                         "<FieldRef Name='Name'/>" +
                                         "<FieldRef Name='RequestID'/>" +
                                         "<FieldRef Name='Path'/>" +
                                         "<FieldRef Name='AttachmentType'/>" +
                                        "</ViewFields><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
                    ListItemCollection collListItem = library.GetItems(camlQuery);
                    clientContext.Load(collListItem);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    itemPosition = collListItem.ListItemCollectionPosition;

                    foreach (ListItem item in collListItem)
                    {

                        if (item.FileSystemObjectType.ToString() == "File")
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    if (itemPosition == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
```

As per my understanding, I can only use the indexed columns in order to query large list and `ID` is an indexed column so why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue occurs when we use `RecursiveAll`. Just curious: do you have many subfolders?

Also, try adding

```
<OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='ID' />
```

before your `<Where>`

Comment: Thanks Denis. Yes there are may subfolders and the above mentioned suggestion is not working. The query should look like this ? `"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='ID' />" +"<Where>" `